# Which is best to use? ADF faces components or trinidad components?

Tags: oracle-adf, trinidad

I recently got to know about trinidad of Apache MYfaces. For web application i have seen peoples using ADF faces components.  Will trinidad components  good for Web Application with rich user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Trinidad and ADF faces components are based on JSF components. ADF faces have component set richer than Trinidad. You can choose based on what type of application you are going to work with.

Answer (score 3):

ADF faces is way overtop primefaces or anyother UI set of components starting from the point that is an oracle product, we know the quality of oracle products!
the binding layer saves you from annotating the backing beans and is easy to use with jdeveloper with the drag and drop feature, plus if you have ADF BC or EJB as backend, and Oracle Database is just a blast no one stops you, that if you really know how to use all of the mentioned.

[ADF Faces DEMO](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/index.jspx;jsessionid=T9HxRlYT2hJLTbQtBGgHFM0GZSg9vVR9CrF9LvqwX41Tc1LhX6vq!-44105662)

Answer (score 1):

They have both solid sets of components. But if you can choose i honestly recommend PRIMEFACES, great rich components, flexible themes.

Give it a chance if you can.

[PRIMEFACES DEMO](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, ADF Faces has more features than Trinidad but usage of ADF requires some license fees when you are not deploying to a weblogic server. The most compelling reason to pick ADF over other ViewController frameworks is if you are also using ADF Business Components as your model layer since RichFaces is optimized(primarily at the data binding layer) for ADF BC.

**ADF Faces is actually based on Trinidad. If you have oracle support license and you've requested for the ADF source, you can see there that the base classes of RichFaces components eventually go back down to the trinidad packages.